# My code wont run properly when other files try to use it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

So my code as been acting up and I don't know what the problem is. When I try to test the file "Battle" it works like it supposed to and everything is fine. It pulls up a tkinter window like I want to, shows the buttons, My sprites, etc. But when I use my main file to run the Battle file it doesn't show the buttons, listbox, or sprites. I looked all over my code and I cant find out whats wrong. If anyone could help me then that would be great! It's a lot of code and I am kinda a rookie so it may not be the cleanest but I do leave a lot of notes.

**This is the Battle code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time

inBattle = False
gameOver = True
i = 0

enemy_type = 0

MAX_HP = 60
MAX_MP = 40

HPval = 20
MPval = 30
POTIONSval = 3

#test
def add_text(recap):
    global i 
    recap.insert(0, 'Damage: ' + str(i))
    i += 1

#switch to turn the whole thing on or off
def GameOver():
    global gameOver
    if gameOver == True:
        gameOver = False
    else:
        gameOver = True

#spells
def Cast_Fireball(spells, MP, recap):
    global MPval

    if MPval - 10 > 0 or MPval - 10 == 0:
        MPval -= 10
        MP.config(text='MP: ' + str(MPval))

        hit = random.randint(0, 100)
        damage = random.randint(1,10) # 1d10

        if hit > 9: # 90%
            recap.insert(0, 'Hit for ' + str(damage))
            spells.destroy()
        else:
            recap.insert(0, 'Missed!')
            spells.destroy()
    else:
        recap.insert(0, 'Not enough mana.')
        spells.destroy()

def Cast_Iceball(spells, MP, recap):
    global MPval

    if MPval - 12 > 0 or MPval - 12 == 0:
        MPval -= 12
        MP.config(text='MP: ' + str(MPval))

        hit = random.randint(0, 100)
        damage = random.randint(1,6) * 2 # 2d6

        if hit > 4: # 95%
            recap.insert(0, 'Hit for ' + str(damage))
            spells.destroy()
        else:
            recap.insert(0, 'Missed!')
            spells.destroy()
    else:
        recap.insert(0, 'Not enough mana.')
        spells.destroy()

def Cast_Heal(spells, HP, MP, recap):
    global MPval
    global HPval

    if MPval - 15 > 0 or MPval - 15 == 0:

        if HPval < MAX_HP:
            MPval -= 15
            MP.config(text='MP: ' + str(MPval))

            damage = random.randint(7,25) # 2d10 + 5

            if HPval + damage > MAX_HP:
                damage = MAX_HP - HPval

            recap.insert(0, 'Healed for ' + str(damage))
            HPval += damage
            HP.config(text='HP: ' + str(HPval))
            spells.destroy()

    else:
        recap.insert(0, 'Not enough mana.')
        spells.destroy()

def Cast_Drain(spells, MP, recap):
    global MPval

    hit = random.randint(0, 100)
    damage = random.randint(1,6) # 1d6

    if hit > 19: # 80%
        recap.insert(0, 'Hit for ' + str(damage))
        recap.insert(0, 'Recovered some mana!')

        MPval += damage
        MP.config(text='MP: ' + str(MPval))
        spells.destroy()
    else:
        recap.insert(0, 'Missed!')
        spells.destroy()


#activates window for spell list
def Spell_list(HP, MP, recap):
    spells = tk.Tk()
    spells.title("Spell List")
    spells.minsize(150,168)

    Fireball = tk.Button(spells, text='Fireball', bg='black', font=("arial", 15, "bold"), fg="white", width=12, command= lambda: Cast_Fireball(spells, MP, recap))
    Fireball.pack()

    Iceball = tk.Button(spells, text='Iceball', bg='black', font=("arial", 15, "bold"), fg="white", width=12, command= lambda: Cast_Iceball(spells, MP, recap))
    Iceball.pack()

    Mana_Drain = tk.Button(spells, text='Mana Drain', bg='black', font=("arial", 15, "bold"), fg="white", width=12, command= lambda: Cast_Drain(spells, MP, recap))
    Mana_Drain.pack()

    Crude_Heal = tk.Button(spells, text='Crude Heal', bg='black', font=("arial", 15, "bold"), fg="white", width=12, command= lambda: Cast_Heal(spells, HP, MP, recap))
    Crude_Heal.pack()

    spells.mainloop()

#drinks a max hp potion and checks if your full already and doesn't use it
def Drink_Potion(HP,POTIONS,recap):
    global HPval
    global POTIONSval

    if POTIONSval > 0 and HPval < MAX_HP:
        temp = MAX_HP - HPval
        HPval = MAX_HP
        POTIONSval -= 1

        recap.insert(0, 'Healed for ' + str(temp))
        HP.config(text="HP: " + str(HPval))
        POTIONS.config(text="Potions: " + str(POTIONSval))

#main fucntion
def Battle():
    #trigger so the player on the other screen is stopped and cant move
    global inBattle
    global HPval
    global MPval
    global POTIONSval
    global enemy_type
    inBattle = True

    #screen settings
    screen = tk.Tk()
    screen.title("Encounter")
    screen.minsize(1000,500)
    screen.configure(bg='black')

    #background settings and rectangle for the bottom half of screen
    canvas = tk.Canvas(screen, width=1000, height=500)
    canvas.configure(bg='black')
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_rectangle(3,300,1000,500,fill='white')

    sprites = tk.Canvas(screen, width=200, height=200, bg='black')
    sprites.place(x=285, y=50)

    #choses which enemy to fight
    #enemy_type = random.randint(0,6)

    #spawning of the enemy
    if enemy_type == 0:
        img = tk.PhotoImage(file='sprites/slime.png')
        sprites.create_image(20,20, image=img, anchor="nw")

    #box on right to list the past actions
    recap = tk.Listbox(screen, font=("arial", 14), bg="white", width=22, height=12)
    recap.place(x=754, y=10)

    #trackers for health, mana, and potions
    HP = tk.Label(screen, text="HP: " + str(HPval), font=("arial",30), bg="white")
    HP.place(x=775, y=310)

    MP = tk.Label(screen, text="MP: " + str(MPval), font=("arial",30), bg="white")
    MP.place(x=775, y=360)

    Potions = tk.Label(screen, text="Potions: " + str(POTIONSval), font=("arial",30), bg="white")
    Potions.place(x=775, y=410)

    #buttons for commands
    Attack = tk.Button(screen,text="Attack",width=9, height=4, bg="black", fg="white", font=("arial", 24, "bold"), command= lambda: add_text(recap))
    Attack.place(x=10, y= 313)

    Defend = tk.Button(screen,text="Defend",width=9, height=4, bg="black", fg="white", font=("arial", 24, "bold"))
    Defend.place(x=200, y= 313)

    Item = tk.Button(screen,text="Item",width=9, height=4, bg="black", fg="white", font=("arial", 24, "bold"), command= lambda: Drink_Potion(HP, Potions, recap))
    Item.place(x=390, y= 313)

    Magic = tk.Button(screen,text="Magic",width=9, height=4, bg="black", fg="white", font=("arial", 24, "bold"), command= lambda: Spell_list(HP, MP, recap))
    Magic.place(x=580, y= 313)



    screen.mainloop()


#testing purposes / comment out on release
#Battle()
```

**This is the Main code:**

```
import random
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
import time
import Battle


callOnce = False

GWIDTH = 800
GHEIGHT = 800

SWIDTH = 50
SHEIGHT = 50

START_Y = 0
END_Y = 0
PLAYER_X = 0
PLAYER_Y = 0

BUFFER = 80

DungeonCord = []
DungeonStorage = []
Treasure = []

pathingPlaces = []
pathingAmount = 0

start = tk.Tk()
start.title("Dungeon Generator")
start.minsize(500,500)

#generate function making it save the set x and y and passing it to the turtle functions
def Generate():
    global GHEIGHT
    global GWIDTH

    Battle.GameOver()
    GWIDTH = xInsert.get()
    GHEIGHT = yInsert.get()
    start.destroy()

DunGenText = tk.Label(text="Dungeon Generator", relief="solid", width = 20, font=("arial", 24, "bold"))
DunGenText.place(x=60, y=35)

xLabel = tk.Label(text="X Grid Count:", width = 10, font=("arial", 14))
xLabel.place(x=145,y=145)

xInsert = tk.Entry(start, width=5)
xInsert.place(x=280,y=150)

yLabel = tk.Label(text="Y Grid Count:", width = 10, font=("arial", 14))
yLabel.place(x=145,y=245)

yInsert = tk.Entry(start, width=5)
yInsert.place(x=280,y=250)

button = tk.Button(start,text="Generate",width=30, bg="black", fg="white", command=Generate)
button.place(x=135, y=450)

start.mainloop()

#main loop for the turtle side of things
while not Battle.gameOver:
    #window settings
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.title("Dungeon Crawler")
    wn.setup(width=(int(GWIDTH) * int(SWIDTH))+BUFFER, height=(int(GHEIGHT) * int(SHEIGHT))+BUFFER)
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    wn.tracer(0)

    #where the grid would start to draw itself
    Gridx = (int(GWIDTH) * int(SWIDTH) * -1) / 2
    Gridy = (int(GHEIGHT) * int(SHEIGHT)) /2

    #this will determine the lowest number between the x axis and the y axis
    if int(GWIDTH) > int(GHEIGHT):
        LOWEST = int(GHEIGHT)
    else:
        LOWEST = int(GWIDTH)

    #this is the formula for the dungeon count in the grid // ((x * y) - 2y) / l
    DCOUNT = ((int(GHEIGHT) * int(GWIDTH)) - (2 * int(GHEIGHT))) / int(LOWEST)

    #the function to draw the grid 
    def draw_grid(t, x, y, sx, sy,):
        for i in range(int(y)):
            for j in range(int(x)):
                t.penup()
                t.goto(x= Gridx + (sx * int(j)), y= Gridy - (sy * int(i)))
                t.pendown()
                t.forward(sx)
                t.right(90)
                t.forward(sx)
                t.right(90)
                t.forward(sx)
                t.right(90)
                t.forward(sx)
                t.right(90)

    #function to draw a square at a location
    def draw_square(t, s):
        for i in range(4):
            t.forward(int(s) * 20)
            t.right(90)

    #drawing the circle on the left side that would be the start
    def draw_start(t, t2):
        global START_Y
        global PLAYER_Y

        START_Y = random.randint(0, int(GHEIGHT) - 1)
        PLAYER_Y = START_Y
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x= Gridx + (SWIDTH / 2), y= (Gridy - (SHEIGHT / 2)) - (SHEIGHT * START_Y) - 10)
        t.pendown()
        t.circle(10)

        t2.penup()
        t2.goto(x= Gridx + (SWIDTH / 2), y= (Gridy - (SHEIGHT / 2)) - (SHEIGHT * START_Y))
        t2.pendown()
        draw_player(t2)

    #drawing a circle on the right side that would be the end
    def draw_end(t):
        global END_Y

        END_Y = random.randint(0, int(GHEIGHT) - 1)
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x= (Gridx + (SWIDTH / 2)) * -1, y= (Gridy - (SHEIGHT / 2)) - (SHEIGHT * END_Y) - 10)
        t.pendown()
        t.circle(10)

    #draws the player at its location
    def draw_player(t):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x= (Gridx + (SWIDTH / 2)) + (SWIDTH * PLAYER_X) - 10, y= (Gridy - (SHEIGHT / 2)) - (SHEIGHT * PLAYER_Y)+3)
        t.pendown()
        for i in range(50): 
            t.forward(20) 
            t.right(144)

    #drawing the dungeon at random locations that can be anyware between the entrance and the exit.
    def draw_dungeons(t, d):
        global DungeonCord
        global Treasure

        for i in range(int(d)):
            closestX = random.randint(1, int(GWIDTH) - 2) 
            closestY = random.randint(0, int(GHEIGHT) - 1)
            DungeonCord.append((closestX,closestY))
            DungeonStorage.append((closestX,closestY))

            for j in range(i):
                if DungeonCord[j] == DungeonCord[i]:
                    closestX = random.randint(1, int(GWIDTH) - 2) 
                    closestY = random.randint(0, int(GHEIGHT) - 1)
                    DungeonCord[i] = (closestX,closestY)
                    DungeonStorage[i] = (closestX,closestY)

                    if DungeonCord[j] == DungeonCord[i]:
                        closestX = random.randint(1, int(GWIDTH) - 2) 
                        closestY = random.randint(0, int(GHEIGHT) - 1)
                        DungeonCord[i] = (closestX,closestY)
                        DungeonStorage[i] = (closestX,closestY)

            #treasure room chance
            TR = random.randint(1,5)

            if TR == 5:
                t.color("yellow")
                Treasure.append(DungeonCord[i])



            t.penup()
            t.goto(x= (Gridx + (SWIDTH / 2)) + (SWIDTH * closestX) - 10, y= (Gridy - (SHEIGHT / 2)) - (SHEIGHT * closestY) + 10)
            t.pendown()
            draw_square(t, 1)
            t.color("white")

    #the pathmaking function that would go to each dungeon and from the start to the end
    def draw_path(t):
        global DungeonCord
        global START_Y
        global END_Y
        global DCOUNT
        global pathingAmount
        global pathingPlaces

        t.penup()
        t.goto(x= Gridx + (SWIDTH / 2), y= (Gridy - (SHEIGHT / 2)) - (SHEIGHT * START_Y))
        t.pendown()

        myCordsx = 0
        myCordsy = START_Y
        dungeon = 0

        for j in range(int(DCOUNT)):

            traveling = True
            closestX = 500
            closestY = 500

            #finds the closest dungeon
            for i in range(int(DCOUNT)):
                x, y = DungeonCord[i]

                if abs(x - myCordsx) + abs(y - myCordsy) < abs(closestX - myCordsx) + abs(closestY - myCordsy):
                    closestX, closestY = x, y
                    dungeon = i
                elif abs(x - myCordsx) + abs(y - myCordsy) == abs(closestX - myCordsx) + abs(closestY - myCordsy):
                    if x < closestX:
                        closestX, closestY = x, y
                        dungeon = i

            #path to the current closest dungeon
            while traveling:
                if closestX > myCordsx: #path right
                    t.forward(int(SWIDTH))
                    myCordsx += 1
                    pathingPlaces.append((myCordsx, myCordsy))
                    pathingAmount +=1
                elif closestY > myCordsy: #path down
                    t.right(90)
                    t.forward(int(SWIDTH))
                    t.left(90)
                    myCordsy += 1
                    pathingPlaces.append((myCordsx, myCordsy))
                    pathingAmount +=1
                elif closestX < myCordsx: #path left
                    t.right(180)
                    t.forward(int(SWIDTH))
                    t.left(180)
                    myCordsx -= 1
                    pathingPlaces.append((myCordsx, myCordsy))
                    pathingAmount +=1
                elif closestY < myCordsy: #path up
                    t.left(90)
                    t.forward(int(SWIDTH))
                    t.right(90)
                    myCordsy -= 1
                    pathingPlaces.append((myCordsx, myCordsy))
                    pathingAmount +=1
                else:
                    traveling = False

            i = 0 #reset on counter            
            DungeonCord[dungeon] = (99, 99) #null entry / dungeon is checked off

        #pathing to the end
        traveling = True
        while traveling:
                if int(GWIDTH) - 1 > myCordsx: #going right
                    t.forward(int(SWIDTH))
                    myCordsx += 1
                    pathingPlaces.append((myCordsx, myCordsy))
                    pathingAmount +=1
                elif END_Y > myCordsy: #going down
                    t.right(90)
                    t.forward(int(SWIDTH))
                    t.left(90)
                    myCordsy += 1
                    pathingPlaces.append((myCordsx, myCordsy))
                    pathingAmount +=1
                elif int(GWIDTH) - 1 != myCordsx and END_Y == myCordsy: #going left
                    t.right(180)
                    t.forward(int(SWIDTH))
                    t.left(180)
                    myCordsx -= 1
                    pathingPlaces.append((myCordsx, myCordsy))
                    pathingAmount +=1
                elif int(GWIDTH) - 1 == myCordsx and END_Y != myCordsy: #going up
                    t.left(90)
                    t.forward(int(SWIDTH))
                    t.right(90)
                    myCordsy -= 1
                    pathingPlaces.append((myCordsx, myCordsy))
                    pathingAmount +=1
                else:
                    traveling = False

    #all the turtle units involved in drawing
    grid = turtle.Turtle()
    grid.hideturtle()
    grid.pencolor("white")

    entrance = turtle.Turtle()
    entrance.hideturtle()
    entrance.pencolor("green")

    end = turtle.Turtle()
    end.hideturtle()
    end.pencolor("red")

    dun = turtle.Turtle()
    dun.hideturtle()
    dun.pencolor("white")
    dun.shape("square")

    path = turtle.Turtle()
    path.hideturtle()
    path.pencolor("green")

    player = turtle.Turtle()
    player.hideturtle()
    player.pencolor("pink")

    #player movement
    def moveUP():
        global PLAYER_X
        global PLAYER_Y
        for i in range(pathingAmount):
            if (PLAYER_X, PLAYER_Y - 1) == pathingPlaces[i] and not Battle.inBattle:
                PLAYER_Y -= 1

                player.clear()
                draw_player(player)

                for i in range(int(DCOUNT)):
                    if (PLAYER_X, PLAYER_Y) == DungeonStorage[i]:
                        Battle.Battle()

                break          

    def moveDOWN():
        global PLAYER_X
        global PLAYER_Y
        for i in range(pathingAmount):
            if (PLAYER_X, PLAYER_Y + 1) == pathingPlaces[i] and not Battle.inBattle:
                PLAYER_Y += 1

                player.clear()
                draw_player(player)

                for i in range(int(DCOUNT)):
                    if (PLAYER_X, PLAYER_Y) == DungeonStorage[i]:
                        Battle.Battle()

                break

    def moveLEFT():
        global PLAYER_X
        global PLAYER_Y
        for i in range(pathingAmount):
            if (PLAYER_X - 1, PLAYER_Y) == pathingPlaces[i] and not Battle.inBattle:
                PLAYER_X -= 1

                player.clear()
                draw_player(player) 

                for i in range(int(DCOUNT)):
                    if (PLAYER_X, PLAYER_Y) == DungeonStorage[i]:
                        Battle.Battle()

                break

    def moveRIGHT():
        global PLAYER_X
        global PLAYER_Y
        for i in range(pathingAmount):
            if (PLAYER_X + 1, PLAYER_Y) == pathingPlaces[i] and not Battle.inBattle:
                PLAYER_X += 1

                player.clear()
                draw_player(player) 

                for i in range(int(DCOUNT)):
                    if (PLAYER_X, PLAYER_Y) == DungeonStorage[i]:
                        Battle.Battle()

                break


    #a call once function so the dungeons, start, and end doesn't keep drawing.
    if callOnce == False:
        draw_grid(grid, GWIDTH, GHEIGHT, SWIDTH, SHEIGHT)
        draw_start(entrance, player)
        draw_end(end)
        draw_dungeons(dun, DCOUNT)
        draw_path(path)

    callOnce = True

    wn.listen()
    wn.onkey(moveRIGHT, "d")
    wn.onkey(moveUP, "w")
    wn.onkey(moveLEFT, "a")
    wn.onkey(moveDOWN, "s")

    while True:
        wn.update()
```

Comment: There are some true and false code that doesn't really do anything right now because im still working on it. just a heads up

Comment: This is way too much code. You need to focus more by creating a [mcve]. If the problem is that no widgets are showing up, you can probably reproduce this with only a single widget. Please take the time to create a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, the problem was tkinter itself. Just needed to change the tk.Tk() in my battle code to tk.Toplevel() since you cant have two tk.Tk() code. Well..... Damn